# How to Send Custom data fields in PayPal Smart Button transaction

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am new to PayPal integrations but I have managed to use the client-side JavaScript SDK to create a button and complete a transaction. I have also added a webhook that listens for PAYMENT.CAPTURE.* events and log the return data into my transactions table in my own database. The downside is I do not have a way of tracking for which service or customer the transaction was. So I would like to know how I can add at least one custom field in the button so that it is returned back to me in the webhook POST so that I can perform some business logic for that particular customer.

My initial alternative was to POST the data return `onApprove:(data, actions)=>{}` but I would have not recovery option if something catastrophic happens before that is done e.g Power outage or general Client-Server connection failure.

Here is my JS basic code for now:

```
try{
        paypal.Buttons({

        // Set up the transaction
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount: {
                        value: charge.amount,
                        currency_code:'USD'
                    }
                }]
            });
        },
        // Finalize the transaction
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                console.log(details);
                if(details.status == "COMPLETED"){
                  localStorage.clear();
                  window.location.href = "thank-you";
                }
                //alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
            });
        }


    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
  }catch(e){
     console.error('PayPal not loaded!');
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Switch to a proper client-server integration.

Follow the [PayPal Checkout integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) guide and make 2 routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order' (see the optional step 5 in 'Add and modify the code'). Both of these routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic, such as saving additional data from form inputs.

(That data can be transfered as part of the `fetch` capture call by adding a `body` key to its options parameter, which can serialize a JSON object for you. Your 2nd server route can then parse that input as JSON and verify it is ok before proceeding with the capture.)

--
Pair those 2 routes with the frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

---

With the above method, you have an immediate, synchronous API response on payment capture. There is no need for an additional asynchronous notification from webhooks, so those will basically become superfluous to you.

Comment: When you say there's no need to use an asynchronous notification, do you basically mean that it isn't necessary to listen for the IPN? That sounds great but I'm wondering how we can trust the data sent from the client to the server via the onApprove method? What server-side check do we need to prevent forgery? Unfortunately the PayPal link you gave above is broken and I'm struggling to find this information in PayPal's dev docs.

Comment: Right. Don't use IPN for this. When createOrder and onApprove calls your server, any data the client sends in the `fetch` request should be verified by your server for sanity, i.e. make sure the price is correct and stock exists to fulfill the order, or whatever else.  If something is wrong, don't proceed with the API capture.

Comment: Updated link in the above, it's now documented in the optional bullet #5 here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/#link-addpaymentbuttons

Comment: Right, yes, I'd definitely do checks on the price and stock etc, but what I actually meant was a way to check and make sure that the actual success status of the API call was genuine and not forged by the client. Without the IPN I'm not sure how I'd go about verifying the authenticity of the API call and the docs (even your updated link) don't seem to make reference to this.

Comment: When the onApprove does a fetch to your server, your server uses the PayPal API to capture the order. The client is not involved in your server receiving the response of success/failure from PayPal. This replaces the asynchronous IPN notification from PayPal to your server.

Comment: Ok, gotcha! Thank you for replying so quickly with that and for the crystal clear explanation!

Answer (score 3):

You *can* switch to a client-server integration (as per @Preston PHK's answer), but for that may be overkill for some applications (and not what the OP asked for).

For a simple purchase where you just need to pass some specific information, you can try leveraging the `purchase_units.invoice_id` field (assuming you don't need that for something else).

The caveat is that the invoice_id needs to be unique every time you use it. This means that you can't just use your customer's internal id. You would need to add something extra to ensure uniqueness.

Your createOrder call might then look something like this:

```
createOrder: function(data, actions) {
    return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
            invoice_id: customerId + "-" + randString,
            amount: {
                value: charge.amount,
                currency_code:'USD'
            }
        }]
    });
},
```

A 6 character random string of alphanumeric (upper and lower) characters gives over 56 billion possibilities, which for most purposes should provide sufficient uniqueness. If you want to be even safer, make it longer. I'm not sure of the exact limit on `invoice_id` but I think it's at least 40 characters.

When you process the transaction (from a webhook) on your server, you just throw away the extra characters.

```
$custId = substr($invoice_id, 0, -7);
```

Comment: invoice_id needs to be unique for each successfully captured transaction, so usually an increment rather than randomness is used. Duplicate payments for the same invoice_id are blocked by default, as a feature

Comment: invoice_id is also visible to the payer as part of the transaction, so a random value is somewhat confusing. The `custom_id` field mentioned in the third answer is a better choice for arbitrary data. Anyway, this is all mostly beside the point since using asynchronous notifications (IPN or webhooks) isn't necessary here and is less secure and robust. A proper client-server integration is the way to go

Answer (score 3):

You can add 'custom_id' field in creareOrder function like that :

```
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.create({
          purchase_units: [{
            custom_id: customValue,
            amount: {
              value: price
            }
          }]
        });
      },
```